# App has photo access, but I never allowed it to access photos

Tags: iphone, photos, privacy

I have a to do list app installed that allows you to add a profile photo. I added the image without ever being asked for access to my photos.

To my understanding, apps that can view your photos should be listed under settings / privacy / photos. This particular app isn’t listed there, what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps with photos access can access all photos in you library whenever the app chooses to in the background without your future confirmation, and can save pictures to the library.

Without photos access, the app can still ask the OS to get the user to choose a picture, at which point iOS can show a system-wide photo chooser and you can choose a single photo. Once you've chosen the photo, just that specific photo is provided by iOS back to the app.

Comment: The app icon  isn’t showing up in settings / privacy / photos. I can upload photos within the app, but there is no way to prevent this app from accessing my photos. Strange.

Comment: @brewpixels Yes, because the app itself doesn't have access to photos. iOS has access to your photos as the OS and can provide individual photos on a per-request basis with your manual consent each time to choose a photo from your library.

Comment: Have you checked Settings > app in question (scroll down to the very bottom of Settings)? There should be a separate switch for photos access.

Comment: @Minorite I see a switch for photos with the Instagram app, but it’s missing for the app in question.

Comment: @Minorite There will only be a switch for apps which request photos access themselves, so the app in question won't show up there.

Comment: @grg Ok, I understand that, but how am I allowed to add photos to a app, without the app asking for access to my photo library? The app in question is Todoist. According to my settings they don’t have access, but Im able to add a profile photo.

Comment: @brewpixels See the second paragraph to my answer, ‘without photos access, the app can still ask the OS to get the user to choose a picture’. In other words, *iOS* is providing read access to the one photo the user selects, which is distinct to giving the *app* access to all your photos independently to the OS, which would otherwise ensure you have to grant individual access to a single photo.

Comment: @grg I understand now thx.